# MySQL NULL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, null, quotes

Is there a way to put a php string variable 'dynamically' in a mysql statement so that if its value is 'NULL' the quotes are removed *within* the query statement? Here's the code:

```
$sql="UPDATE products SET title='$title', supplier='$supplier', availability='$availability', condition='$condition', brand='$brand', power='$power', category='$category', min_qty='$min_qty', cost='$cost' WHERE id='$id'";
```

All the variables are strings, however I want that if one of these strings is 'NULL', it is effectively treated as mysql NULL (and not as the 'NULL' string). Is there a quick way to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use prepared statements

Comment: are you using pdo or mysqli?

Comment: @jan I tried your code but I get this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'.

Comment: I solved using mysqli prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$sql="UPDATE products SET title='$title', supplier='$supplier', availability='$availability', condition=".($condition != null) ? "(".$condition.")" : "NULL"", brand='$brand', power='$power', category='$category', min_qty='$min_qty', cost='$cost' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Look at $condition. This is an easy way to act with if-statements in strings.

Comment: These statements are known as Ternary Operators: http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: Easy and poor. You should be using prepared statements.

Comment: @RobertDundon: Known as the _conditional operator_, strictly. Lots of reference material (even the PHP manual, in places) gets this wrong, though. The conditional operators is an (the only, at present) example of _a_ ternary operator.